# What does positional PICK on an object do in Rebol 2, and what's the equivalent Rebol 3?

Tags: object, rebol

In Rebol 2:

```
>> foo: make object! [a: 10 b: 20]

>> foo/a
== 10

>> foo/b
== 20

>> first foo
== [self a b]

>> second foo
== [make object! [
        a: 10
        b: 20
    ] 10 20]

>> third foo
== [a: 10 b: 20]

>> fourth foo
** Script Error: fourth expected series argument of type:
   series date port tuple event
** Near: fourth foo
```

So you can pick out of it as if it were a block for values 1, 2, 3.  But doing positional selection is right out in Rebol 3:

```
>> first foo
** Script error: cannot use pick on object! value
** Where: first
** Near: first foo
```

I gather that this is deprecated now (like picking out of a function to get its parameter list).  However, I'm trying to translate some code that says something like:

```
bar: construct/with (third foo) mumble
```

(a) What is the point of that code?

(b) How would I translate it to Rebol 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Construct builds the object without evaluating the spec block. This implies that the spec is of `some [set-word! any-type!]` form (which it would always be if you are using the body of another object). Construct/with uses a second object (`mumble`) as the prototype.

b) Object operations appear to have changed as follows:

i) `first object` is replaced by `words-of object`

ii) `second object` is replaced by `values-of object`

iii) `third object` is replaced by `body-of object` <strike>or `to block! object`</strike>

Therefore your code can be replaced with:

```
bar: construct/with body-of foo mumble
```

Comment: Ah nice.  And it appears BODY-OF is available in R2 as well (R2/forward?)

Comment: Yup, R2/Forward. Added to R2 from there.

Answer (score 5):

This usage of `first`, `second`, `third`, etc for reflection is indeed deprecated (and it's probably quite obvious why).

The general replacement is [REFLECT](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/reflect.html), which takes a FIELD parameter to specify what information is to be extracted.

REFLECT is in turn wrapped by a group of functions (referred to by some as "reflectors") for convenience: SPEC-OF, BODY-OF, WORDS-OF, VALUES-OF, etc. Those are the preferred replacement for reflection using FIRST et al. Luckily, those "reflectors" have been backported to R2 (2.7.7+) as well.

**How to translate `third foo` to Rebol 3?**

The counterpart to reflective THIRD on an object is BODY-OF.

**What is the point of the `construct/with (third a) b` idiom?**

It allows you to construct a new object by *merging* A and B (with values from A taking precedence over B).

So you could, for example, use this idiom to create a full "options" object by merging actual user-provided options with an object of defaults.